# bootstrap-datepicker not getting shimmed with requirejs

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, twitter-bootstrap, requirejs

I am building  a application with backbone.js + require.js. I want to use datepicker from here in my application: [datepicker](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/)

Since its non-AMD, i shim it in requirejs like this:

```
require.config({
baseUrl: "appjs",

paths:{
    jquery: '../layout_assets/assets/js/libs/jquery-1.8.2.min',
    dt: '../layout_assets/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min',
    dtPlugins:'../layout_assets/plugins/datatables/dtplugins',
    dtBootstrap: '../layout_assets/plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap',
    underscore: '../assets/js/underscore-min',
    Backbone: '../assets/js/backbone-min',
    bootstrap: '../assets/js/bootstrap.min',
    datepicker:'../layout_assets/bootstrap-datepicker'
    },

    shim: {
        underscore:{
            exports:"_"
        },

        Backbone:{
            deps: ['underscore','jquery'],
            exports: "Backbone"
        },

        dt: {
        deps:['jquery'],
        exports: "dt"   
        },

        dtPlugins: {
            deps:['jquery','dt'],
            exports:"dtPlugins"
            },
        bootstrap: {
        deps:['jquery'],
        exports:"bootstrap"

        },
        dtBootstrap: {
            deps: ['dt','jquery'],
            exports: "dtBootstrap"
        },

        datepicker:{
        deps:['jquery','bootstrap'],
        exports:"datepicker"
        }

        }

});
```

Now in one of my views i call datepicker like this:

```
define(['Backbone',
        'underscore',
        'jquery',
        'datepicker',
        'models/reports',
        'dtBootstrap',
        'bootstrap',
        'text!templates/reports/dashboard.html',
        ],function(Backbone,_,$,dp,report,dtBootstrap,bootstrap,dashboard){


        var view=Backbone.View.extend({
            el:"#content-wrap",
            template:_.template(dashboard),
            render:function(){
            this.$("#container-left").html(this.template());
            console.log(dp);
            }

    });
    return view;
    });
```

This returns undefined on the console. I guess the library is not getting shimmed properly.

Comment: I also have the same problem.  Did you ever find a fix for this?

Answer (score 5):

This is the shim that I use:

```
"datepicker" : {
    deps: ["jquery-ui", "bootstrap"],
    exports: "$.fn.datepicker"
}
```

for

```
"datepicker": "lib/datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker"
```

Comment: is jquery-ui necessary?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at `datepicker`'s source it looks like it doesn't in fact export anything - that's why `requirejs` can't find the global `dt` variable to "connect" to (`window.dt` if run in browser environment). According to `datepicker`'s website, it just adds its function to jQuery object, it's not supposed to be used as a standalone instance. Example from its [docs page](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/):

```
$('#dp5').datepicker()
  .on('changeDate', function(ev){
    if (ev.date.valueOf() < startDate.valueOf()){
      ....
    }
```

});

Have you tried something like that?

I believe shimming is not necessary in this case.