# When to use shim in requirejs

Tags: knockout.js, twitter-bootstrap-3, requirejs

I was trying to add a custom knockout binding to the [bootstrap-datepicker](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/release/#) and came into the solution in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15085504/bootstrap-datepicker-not-getting-shimmed-with-requirejs) just before mimic that one and without putting it into the javascript asp bundle I tried to add the bootstrap-datepicker.js to the requirejs config in this way

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        'text': '../Scripts/text',
        'durandal': '../Scripts/durandal',
        'plugins': '../Scripts/durandal/plugins',
        'transitions': '../Scripts/durandal/transitions',
        'bootstrap.datepicker': '../Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker'
    }
});

define('jquery', function () { return jQuery; });
define('knockout', ko);
```

After that I'm able to add the custom binding in a module just referencing bootstrap.datepicker like this

```
define(['jquery', 'bootstrap.datepicker'], function () {
    ko.bindingHandlers.datepicker = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
            //initialize datepicker with some optional options
            var options = allBindingsAccessor().datepickerOptions || {};
            $(element).datepicker(options).on("changeDate", function (ev) {
                var observable = valueAccessor();
                observable(ev.date);
            });
        },
        update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
            var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
            $(element).datepicker("setValue", value);
        }
    };
});
```

And I'm lost why I don't need to wrap it in a amd module (as done with jquery or knockout) or in the index.cshtml js bundle so my question is when is going to be needed a shim? can I follow this to other libraries?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is working for you, then **bootstrap.datepicker** is actually *supporting* AMD.  For those libraries that support AMD directly, in most cases specifying a path to that library and then just requiring it elsewhere is sufficient.

Complications can arise when those libraries have dependencies of their own that may or may not support AMD.  This can necessitate using some of the more esoteric features of RequireJS.

A shim is used when a library does not return an object that RequireJS can use.  So, we have to *shim*, or shoehorn, the object into Require's space.